# I am trying to search a database with values from combo boxes

Tags: c#, sql, select, where-clause

I am familiar with SQL syntax and am trying to create a windows form in C#. My goal is to achieve something like this:

```
Select * 
From comboBox1 
Where Name = comboBox2 And Station = comboBox3
```

Here is my code:

```
private void searchBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=WIN-0P8I7F78SRV\SQLEXPRESS02;Initial      Catalog=bakFile;Integrated Security=True");

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(String.Concat("Select * From ", watershedCombo.Text), con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    dt.TableName = "Bluemountains";

    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
```

[Running form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snXJA.png)

It retrieves the info from the database on the combo box but I am not sure how to further filter it using the values from the other comboboxes.

Just to clarify, in the running form, Watershed = comboBox1

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like a bad idea to just accept any input from the user and inject it straight into your query. Also why do all your tables have a `Name` and `Station` column, sounds like you should rethink your design.

Comment: "I am familiar with SQL" - are you familiar with SQL injection?

Comment: Name column has the name of the bacteria and the Station is the area of the water that the bacteria was collected from. The idea is to filter the information by name and station, for example, Garramidae from R1.

Comment: Yes, I am familiar with SQL Injection and that is not what the question is asking. All I am asking for is how to include the other combo boxes in my query. This is not for release but for myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand is that you have one table per watershed and each watershed table has (at least) a `Name` and a `Station`. My inner software architect gets triggered by such a design but I will keep him quiet.

So what I would do is to use a *parametrized query*. The basic idea is that you define a SQL-query with placeholders for values that you will feed in dynamically.

I have no way of actually testing this but something along these lines should do the trick:

```cs
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=WIN-0P8I7F78SRV\SQLEXPRESS02;Initial      Catalog=bakFile;Integrated Security=True"))
{
    connection.Open();
    
    var cmd = new SqlCommand($"SELECT * FROM {watershedCombo.Text} WHERE Name = @Name AND Station = @Station", connection);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", nameCombo.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Station", stationCombo.Text);
    
    var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    var dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    dt.TableName = "Bluemountains";

    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
```

The `@`-prefixed strings are considered *parameters*. Those are replaced with actual values through `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ParamName", <ParamValue>)`

You can read more about parameters in the C# docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) or [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/commands-and-parameters)

**Update:**
I forgot that you can not use a table name as a parameter. Sorry. Updated my answer.

Comment: `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataAdapter` need `using` as well